# How to convert this Unityscript to C#? [Ignore please]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code in C# whats wrong with it?:
can someone please find error in this code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class qwe : MonoBehaviour {

    void  Update (){
        float xP = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime * 20; 
        transform.Translate(Vector3 xe = new Vector3(xP,0,0));
        transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, -10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is not a _code converter_.

Comment: It may help if you could give us error it gives you ...

Comment: A screenshot of a code snippet, really?!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class qwe : MonoBehaviour {

    void  Update (){
        float xP = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime * 20;
        Vector3 xe = new Vector3(xP,0,0);
        transform.Translate(xe);
        float x = Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, -10, 10);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  "Vector3 xe = "
Try this:

```
float xP = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime * 20; 
transform.Translate(new Vector3(xP,0,0));
transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, -10, 10);
```

UPD: Oh, and [Cattwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3983798/cattwood) is right — you can't modify only x. You should create new Vector3 variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change one value of a Vector3, like you have done with the x value. You need to create a new Vector3 and assign it to transform.position